# Media Files not Displaying in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to display user-uploaded images on a webpage. When I upload the image files using the Django admin interface (I made a model for gallery images with a filefield), the image is stored in /media/images correctly. I have my media settings set in settings.py as follows:

```
MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
```

Project urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
import gallery.views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^', include('gallery.urls')),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root = settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Gallery urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^', views.homepage, name = 'home'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Gallery views.py:

```
def homepage(request):
    texts = Sitetext.objects.all()
    gal = Galleryimg.objects.all()
    gal.order_by('position')


return render(request,'index.html', {"text1":texts[0].text,"text2":texts[1].text,"text3":texts[2].text,"text4":texts[3].text,"title1":texts[0].title,"title2":texts[1].title,"title3":texts[2].title,"title4":texts[3].title,"gallery":gal})
```

And then this is the part of the template code that accesses the image:

```
{% for g in gallery %}
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="g.imgfile.url" />
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

When I create a gallery image, a broken image pops up, but the image is not accessed correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Remove the `static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)` part, from your `gallery.urls` file.
2. Replace `src="g.imgfile.url"` with `src="{{ g.imgfile.url }}"`.

*Aside question:* Why do you pass this big dictionary (`{"text1":texts[0].text,...`) to your template? It is error prone and bad practice. You should just pass `'texts': texts` and inside your template iterate over them with a `{% for text in texts %}` [forloop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for). So, the `render` method should be something like `render(request, 'index.html', {'texts': texts, 'gallery': gal})`.

Comment: I did both 1. and 2. and the file is still not displaying. The url is correct I believe because:

    In [3]: from gallery.models import Galleryimg

    In [4]: Galleryimg.objects.all()
    Out[4]: <QuerySet [<Galleryimg: Galleryimg object>]>

    In [5]: Galleryimg.objects.all()[0]
    Out[5]: <Galleryimg: Galleryimg object>

    In [6]: Galleryimg.objects.all()[0].imgfile
    Out[6]: <FieldFile: images/20150223_083553.jpg>

    In [7]: Galleryimg.objects.all()[0].imgfile.url
    Out[7]: '/media/images/20150223_083553.jpg'

Comment: So, if you hit the url `127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/20150223_083553.jpg`, you get a 404, right? If so, try this: Inside your `urls.py` file put this at top `from django.views.static import serve`, remove `static(settings.MEDIA_URL...)` and add `urlpatterns += [url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)', serve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT})]`.

Comment: Nope, the image loads nicely.

Comment: Ah! I changed my URLs file and now it displays! Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please, provide more info in order to help others too. Maybe update my answer to reflect the changes.

Comment: Previously I had set my urls to encompass any request, and when I did this the image did not load. When I set the homepage specifically to "/home/" I was able then to access the files, because previously the requests for the files had been redirected to the home page.

Answer (score 3):

I do this and I am able to serve media files from the Django development server:

```
urlpatterns += [
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', django.views.static.serve, {
    'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),]
```

It should be enough to include that just in the project urls.py.

The issue with yours could be that your media URL entry in urls.py is not correct.  You seem to be not matching the actual URL of the media file, which is probably something like `/media/something.png`.  You seem to be just qualifying on `/media/`.  I also think your regex should be `^media/`, not `/media/`.

Answer (score 0):

Also make sure you don't have a wild card url pattern that overrides the media URL /media/ in other apps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34532486)